# Wix elevated AND impersonating Custom Action

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a custom action that needs to modify registry settings:

- it is marked as `deferred` in order to support a rollback
- it must be run with elevated priviliges in order to modify the Registry
- it must be run within the security context of a **particular user** (impersonated)

```
    <CustomAction Id="EncryptRegistrySettings"
                BinaryKey="DLServiceCA"
                DllEntry="EncryptRegistrySettings"
                Execute="deferred"
                Impersonate="yes"
                Return="check"/>
```

I have some other ugly options to workaround this problem (`Execute="immediate"` or `impersonate="yes"` with elevated subprocess) which I don't want to resort to.

The problem is: with `Impersonate="no"` subprocess `msiexec` is run by `SYSTEM`. With `yes` it is run by `User`, but not elevated.

So the question is:
**Is it possible to run a Custom Action both as Impersonated AND elevated?**

Comment: Why do you need to impersonate to modify an elevated key?

Comment: @RobMensching I didn't say I need impersonation for registry. For that I need elevation. Impersonation is needed for another reason (a service is running that prevents anauthorized users from accessing secured data. Reg keys included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are mutually exclusive capabilities in Windows Installer.